# Is it possible to save a file with name containing ' " > () =,

Tags: file, save, filenames

For example:  '">sometext<.txt

I am currently trying to save a file in that form, so If I upload the file on a website I'm hopping to find the XSS bug.

Comment: What system are you running on? What server-side software platform are you targeting?

Comment: ^ Your question is missing a lot of details. Please update your question.

Answer (score 3):

Windows (but not necessarily NTFS) prohibits the following characters in filenames: `\/:*?"<>|`, which precludes the characters necessary for most XSS attacks (`<>"`). Windows also disallows reserved DOS device file-names like `COM`, `NUL`, etc (though it is possible to create a file with that name, it cannot be done using the normal Win32 filesystem API).

Linux (and UNIX and POSIX in general) is more permissive: every character is allowed in a filename except for `/` (the directory separator character) and `\0` (NULL, a raw zero).

I imagine an insecure web-application that saves uploaded files with their filenames intact and without having sanitized filenames probably will succumb to an XSS attack - unless they're also careful to never render HTML raw.

Comment: Hm so it isn't possible saving like <script>alert('"Jsmth");</script> as a filename? Because windows/unix doesn't allow that characters? Does a other way exists that a filename hasn't got a "rule" , how it's saved?

Comment: @TiZaLjubavNisiRodjena Some applications (including some I've developed myself) store files in a database or "offloaded" storage like Azure Blob Storage, where filenames are stored as arbitrary strings without any restrictions, but I always render user-supplied values after `HtmlEncode()` to prevent XSS in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows prohibits these characters. But you could try Azure Blob Storage